# How do I prevent that the Status Bar overlaps my App?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ios7

How do I prevent that my iPhone app overlaps my app? I want that the app screen starts below the status bar as is was in previous versions of iOS prior to iOS7.

The following image shows an example of a demo app where the app is overlapped by the status bar as marked with blue.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Cordova plugin [StatusBarPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/StatusBarPlugin) to change the status bar overlay. You can set the method below to start the app below the status bar in iOS7:

```
StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
```

If you are using phonegap-build you can include [StatusBarPlugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/505) directly

Or you can also do this directly in Objective-C in MainViewController.m by offsetting the webview by 20px:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
    CGRect appView = [self.webView bounds];
    appView.origin.y = 20;
    appView.size.height = appView.size.height - 20;
    self.webView.frame = appView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try create a category like this

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_OF_DEVICE_LESS_THAN(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
@implementation UIViewController (iOS7)
{
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    if (!SYSTEM_VERSION_OF_DEVICE_LESS_THAN(@"7.0"))
    {
        CGRect viewBounds=self.view.bounds;
        CGFloat topBarOffset=self.topLayoutGuide.length;
        viewBounds.origin.y=topBarOffset*-1;
        self.view.bounds=viewBounds;
    }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you tagged Cordova but if you have access to the ViewController that the Cordova content is displayed in then add the following within viewDidLoad.

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)])
{
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

Rather than checking system versions you should test for functionality within that version of iOS.